# How to include Font-family from a url in style sheet

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use a font (Parkinson Italic) in my html page but that font is not available in my dearmweaver font-family drop down. Can i set the font-family from a URL ?

Comment: hmm... same question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code

`@font-face {
    font-family: yourfont;
    src: url(your_font_url);
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

put it in your CSS file, I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to embed fonts from remote sources.

For example to use the Roboto font from Google's Font service you would add a LINK in the the HEAD of your HTML file:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

And in the stylesheet

```
body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

In any case the desired font must be available when the client displays the page. You can host your own or use a free service like mentioned above.

*Note : it seems that [Parkinson](https://store.typenetwork.com/foundry/fontbureau/fonts/parkinson/medium-italic) is not a free font.*

Comment: from where did you checked that parkinson is not a free font ? I basically need a website from where i cant use the fonts. Other than google fonts page

Comment: sorry i mis understood you... thanks for the support.. Cheers